# How to change CSS styles for certain dates on jQuery DatePicker?

Tags: css, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using the Jquery datepicker and everything is working fine and all styled how i want apart from any events i have in the database.

I would like any day that has an event to have a style using .my_class so instead of the default styling, it has a different colour.  I would like this to apply for days that are in other months so if there's an event on the 1st of the next month, then style that.

I have used this to style the days of the other months to how i want but using something similar for the days with events doesn't work.

This works by changing the background colour of the other months

```
.ui-datepicker-other-month.ui-state-disabled:not(.my_class) span {
    background: #fff;
    color: #b4b3b3;    
}
```

This doesn't work

```
.ui-datepicker-other-month.ui-state-disabled .my_class span {
    background: #f00;
    color: #b4b3b3;    
}
```

This is the jquery for the datepicker and adding .my_class to any table cells that have an event

```
var selected_dates = new Array();
    // gets all the events from the database using AJAX
    selected_dates = getSelectedDates();

    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        inline: true,
        dateFormat: 'yy-m-d',
        showOtherMonths: true,
        dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
        beforeShowDay: function (date)
        {
            // gets the current month, day and year
            // Attention: the month counting starts from 0 that's why you'll need to +1 to get the month right
            var mm = date.getMonth() + 1,
                dd = date.getDate(),
                yy = date.getFullYear();
            var dt = yy + "-" + mm + "-" + dd;

            if(typeof selected_dates[dt] != 'undefined')
            {
                // puts a special class to the dates in which you have events, so that you could distinguish it from the other ones
                // the "true" parameter is used to know which are the clickable dates
                return [true, " my_class"];
            }

            return [false, ""];
        },
        onSelect: function(date)
        {
            // puts the event's title in the dialog box
            $("#dialog").attr("title",selected_dates[date]['event_title']); // for the first time you open the popup
            $("#dialog").dialog("option","title",selected_dates[date]['event_title']);
            // puts the event's description text in the dialog box
            $("#dialog").text(selected_dates[date]['event_description']);
            // show the dialog box
            $("#dialog" ).dialog();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Removed the space, maybe? Not sure what you rly mean tho..

```
.ui-datepicker-other-month.ui-state-disabled.my_class span {
    background: #f00;
    color: #b4b3b3;    
}
```